# Where are the values for the "Updates Status" in Windows 10 held?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Like many of you, I work in a company environment, with Windows update cycles on the Windows 10 OS being the bane of my sysadmin life and my "power" users lives.

Firstly, we have configured windows updates to be as intrusive as possible when it comes to notifying the users, but for some of our most senior staff, who are away from there desks a lot, they miss the notifications from the system tray, and other warnings, to be greeted with a message saying:

"Your computer will reboot at 12:00pm" at about 11:55am, much to their annoyance.

So, to mitigate the issue as much as possible (BTW, we don't want to give them control over when to install patches, as this is a massive security issue) we will be emailing the user of each terminal with an email to say that there machine is due for a reboot, via a nifty little PS script [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-PendingReboot-Query-bdb79542) to find out if a machine is requesting a reboot pending.

now, this is working great, with some output similar to this:

> Hi Fred,
>
> Your Computer W10-25 has been marked for reboot due to pending Windows Updates, please ensure you have saved your work before the end of the day just in case!
>
> Regards
>
> IT Dept.

Now, in the Updates section of the ms-settings, it will tell you when its *supposed* to reboot:

[image: shown here]

Now there is usually a set time that is displayed here, and I would like to send that in the email to the users to be a bit more specific.

**So the question:**
Can someone please help me retrieve this information from the registry or where-ever it is held?

Comment: Did you meant use the word "intrusive", it means disruptive, which means you are purposefully making it hard on everyone?

Comment: "can someone please help me retrieve this information from the registry or where-ever it is held?" - This is handled by a group policy, I don't have a Windows 10 machine in front of me, if you tell me the group policy that is configured when this time is set I can provide you the location in the registry.

Comment: @Ramhound what i meant by intrusive, is that it tells you as much as possible in advance that it will be rebooting.

Comment: @Ramhound, maybe i need to clarify my request, it is the time that the PC decides when it will be rebooting based on the individual PC's use that i need to retrieve, therefore this must be held locally in the registry, afaik, this cannot be governed by the central GPO settings propagated to clients.

Comment: I am actually aware of that....The selection by the user sets a group policy on the local machine itself.

Comment: @Ramhound understood, so in theory, you are saying the time the PC is saying it will reboot is held in the GPO, so to come back to your question, i don't know which local GPO is set. That is my question.

Comment: I knew I was right but [Manage device restarts after updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart), outlines the policy and key in question, but I am also actually shocked I knew that.

Comment: i have yet to test the details in the Documentation, but that is THE most comprehensive document i have seen with regards to Windows 10 updates! thank you @Ramhound, can you put this in as an answer, and i will mark it as accepted, hopefully this will help others too!

Comment: Since I don't know how exactly you are going to solve your problem, feel free to answer this question, you are in the best position to know what exactly was helpful about it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The setting for the time of the reboot will either be set by Active Hours or a defined time set by the user, depending on the windows build, the GPO settings applied to the machine and the period in which each device is in with regards to its update schedule (could be Scheduled auto-restart or Engaged restart periods) all detailed by the document: [Manage device restarts after updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart)

We decided to use the registry values to remind the users that a restart would be performed outside of those hours.

```
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\ActiveHoursStart

HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\ActiveHoursEnd

if 

HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\SetActiveHours = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you aren't using WSUS or SCCM to manage updates? It sounds like you have the clients going to MS Update and that's a recipe for frustration and eventual disaster. Not to mention you get far greater control over when updates are installed.

Comment: we use WSUS (SCCM is to expensive for the size of our organisation) to manage which updates are approved to be installed to various different machine groups, afaik, you cannot manage notifications and reboot schedules purely with WSUS.